# how to synchronize webservice calls in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services, asynchronous

I have a control application - using asp.net webservices.

I have a timer which does an asynchronous webservice call every 5 seconds to update the screen.There are also user buttons to refresh parts of the screen, also doing async webservice calls.

The issue is my screen get messy if a user webservice command is issued before the timer webservice response has arrived.
Basically, I want the user command to wait, if there is a pending async timer call in process. How do I synchronize between these calls in Javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to ignore the timed postback when a user postback occurs?

If so, set 2 flags (DontRequest and IgnoreNext) when the user does postback. When the user postback returns, unset DontRequest.

Your automated process would not start requests while DontRequest is set. If a response is received and IgnoreNext is set, ignore the response and unset the flag.